# How would I hightlight the changes in exel on macbook pro

Tags: excel-2016

I am using excel 15.37 on Macbook pro. I want to track changes in my excel. I tried the method mentioned in https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-change-tracking-on-or-off-96169f55-89c3-4fe4-a502-333e426ba9b1 but I do not find the same options because of Macbook version of excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options are available but it is different than the excel in Window. Go to Tools and then Track Changes. You can highlight changes if you want.